# meaning of "obvious statement" and "the form of lengthy"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I've come across those two statements in an article and not been able to understand what they mean. Can anyone please explain their meanings to me?

As in the sentences below:

"...those who are tech-savvy might roll their eyes at the obvious statement that the internet works as a contemporary CV, but might not be familiar with the cultivation of the face to face interview..."

"What makes this book draw the attention from others is its interactive nature as it makes demands of its reader in the form of lengthy exercises to be done."

Thank you for any help you can offer

Comment: Ideally you should avoid asking two separate questions at the same time as the StackExchange format can make it difficult to choose a single accepted answer to both questions.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the "statement" is that "the internet works as a contemporary CV". The writer thinks that it is obvious that this statement is true.

As to your second example, the words "form of lengthy" don't belong together. The book "makes demands of its reader". What form do these demands have? "Lengthy exercises to be done". (The word "lengthy" could be removed from the sentence, and it would mean nearly the same thing.)

Comment: They' ve become clear to me now. Thank you for your help and time Rosie.